# javascript onblur in ie allowing other text to be clicked and then fires the event

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, focus, onblur, asp.net-validators

I have a form in which i have used asp.net validators. Along with the by default behavior of Asp.net validators i need them to fire onblur and gain the focus back so that user should not escape from that box. I did the following method in javascript and called them.

The following is my js function

```js
 function callMyValidators(a,b) {
        var validator = document.getElementById(a);
        ValidatorValidate(validator);
        if ((document.getElementById(a)).style.visibility == "visible")
            document.getElementById(b).focus();
    }
```

I call them in each textbox onblur by

```html
onblur="callMyValidators('RangeValidator2','txtPOBOX')"
```

In google chrome its working fine. But in IE it allows other text boxes to be clicked and then only firing the onblur event of current textbox. Since the second text box is being clicked the onblur event of both the textboxes fire and they mutually fight each other to focus, leaving the page hanged up.

How can I solve it. Please help. Any help much appreciated.

Comment: It probably isn't the best UX to force the user to stay in the textbox you choose. Though you could do something like store which box is currently chosen, and if the event is fired for a different box, ignore it.

Comment: @RobFoley Thank you for your response. Can u just make it clear for me with a code snippet please. I am not sure how to do it